# Apple Mail opening mail in new window when clicking notification

Tags: macos, mail.app, notifications

When clicking the notification from Apple's Mail client it opens the mail in a new window, instead of showing the mail window (Which is in its own separate space) like it has done previously. Does anyone know if this behavior can be changed?

I have verified on another computer that this is a "feature" in the latest version of OS X (10.9.2). So my question is now how to disable it?

Comment: I've looked through the Preference Panes of Mail and Notification Center respectively without finding a setting. Also browsed `com.apple.mail` user defaults and tried running `strings` on the 10.9.2 version of Mail, again with no luck.

Comment: Yeah, I also looked though all the settings without finding anything. This is an incredibly stupid change, which will hopefully piss of enough people to make them change it back in the next update.

Comment: I agree, this is really irritating. Someone ping me if this is ever solved.

Comment: Looks like Apple has a [Mail feedback page](http://www.apple.com/feedback/mail.html), submit a complaint there.

Comment: Left a bug report, I have the feeling the will never get red but one can always hope ;)

Comment: also sent to apple via the link above. Also emailed a link to this page in my complaint so they will check. Thanks for posting!! Tyrel

Comment: I also sent a report. I'm really not digging this change.

Comment: This is indeed a new *feature*, with no off switch, and it's totally messing with my feng shui.

Comment: This is especially annoying if you use Mail in full screen mode—if you have a compose window open, clicking notifications silently fails.

Comment: Yes, I've noticed the same behavior. Let's hope it goes away in Yosemite.

Comment: (Narrator: It did not go away)

Comment: Nearly 10 years later and I've learned to live with it. Still don't like it though.

Answer (score 6):

This is a feature of OS X Mavericks (10.9.2) and cannot be disabled

Comment: I know, this is noted in the original question. This post should probably not be an answer.

Comment: @rick we don't generally ask people to not answer - even if the answer is wrong. In this case, the opinion at it can't be disabled makes it a good answer in my opinion (hence my upvote) and others are of course free to downvote it as has already happened.

Comment: Like so many post Snow Leopard bugs, they just pretend it's a 'feature'.